# how to use byte imag[] array instead of string mString[] array in android lazy list application

Tags: android, lazylist

I am new developer I would like to use lazy list concept in a sample application.  In Lazy List application the developers has used an url that url has converted in to Bitmap.  But I would like to use bitmap encoded string array.  The encoded string array has converted in to byte array by using Base64.java.  I would like to use the byte array instead of url.
In lazy list application they have used a string array as :

```
      private String[] mStrings={"url1","url2","url3","url4","url5"};
```

In my sample application I have used a byte array as:

```
         byte[] imgArry= Base64.decode(photoInfo);                  
            Bitmap bit=BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(imgArry,0,imgArry.length);     
            profileImageView.setImageBitmap(bit);
```

From the above code I would like to pass byte[] imgArry instead of String[] mStrings to:

```
        adapter=new LazyAdapter(this, imgArry);
```

How can I use byte[] array instead of String[] mStrings?

Comment: The shift key on your keyboard doesn't seem to work consistently.  Perhaps you should replace it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a new constructor to your LazyAdapter class that accepts byte[] as the second parameter.

If you are doing this you could either directly edit the LazyAdapter class or simply create a subclass with a constructor that takes the bitmap or byte[] as the second paramter.